# Restore Enigmail Private Keys from file system on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird, gnupg, enigmail

I want to restore my private OpenPGP keys from a deja-dup backup of the file-system the old Ubuntu installation was running on.

The backup is already extracted and as I understood from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/386851/public-private-key-locations-with-enigmail-and-thunderbird-on-windows#386897) my keys are stored at the old user directory as `.gnupg/secring.gpg`

So how can I recover the private OpenPGP keys from that file without breaking or replacing my new keyring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply import the file by running `gpg --import <filename>` on the command line.